# How to Do Mapping of Xml output from Simul8 to Access Output of Arena

Tags: simulation, software-design, simulate, arena-simulation

I am using two softwares Simul8 and Arena

I want to know how can I map XML Output given by simul8 to Access output of Arena and vice-versa

Comment: It is expected that you make an attempt and share that code, then it is much easier to get help.

Comment: I am having xml file that is output of simul8 and Access Output file of Access 

This is pdf for parameters that output files of both contains 

http://www.courses.vcu.edu/MATH-jrm/OPER641/Papers/CapitalOneSimulationCourse.pdf

Comment: Simul8 generates and accept XML file . Arena Generate and accept Access File

But i want to map simul8 and arena output  So that I can have a software that can map xml generated by simul8 to Access then i can load that access output to arena